# Get new version (v2) of stampit from bower

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, stampit.js

I want to get the v2 version of stampit just by typing the 'bower install'.

I also set in bower config like this

```
"stampit": "git://github.com/ericelliott/stampit#v2_0"
```

and it seems that it did not created a compiled / dist for this new script. What's the best solution for this or any other alternatives? did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

stampit is available via bower: https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit-bower

`$ bower install stampit`

It provides standard UMD package.

UPD:

Install any version like this:

`bower install stampit=https://npmcdn.com/stampit@4.1.1/dist/stampit.min.js`

or

`bower install stampit=https://unpkg.com/stampit@4.1.1/dist/stampit.min.js`